# Read parquet file using pd.read_parquet looking for a schema

Tags: pandas, unit-testing, parquet, fastparquet

I'm working on an app that is writing parquet files.
For testing purposes, I'm trying to read a generated file with pd.read_parquet.
I get a really strange error that asks for a schema:

self = <[AttributeError("'ParquetFile' object has no attribute '_schema'") raised in repr()] ParquetFile object at 0x7fae6e06b250>

This happen on the following line:

```
data = pd.read_parquet(file)
```

where file is the path to file from root content. First I'm not supposed to provide a schema as we're talking about parquet here and I'm not sure what could cause the issue. Maybe a readability clause ?

The generated file looks good when I imported it in my Parquet plugin for pycharm

> {"Id": 12345, "Limit": 200, "Product": 818}
> {"Id": 67890, "Limit":3000, "Product": 819}
> So it shouldn't be an issue with the input data.

NB: Tried the same with fastparquet and got the same error (makes sense as pd.read_parquer is based on it.

Comment: This sounds most likely like an environment issue.  How are you installing pandas?  Did you try with pyarrow as the read parquet engine?  What version of libraries are you using?

Comment: By importing it in the requirements section, using pandas==1.1.5.
I tried with pyarrow and I think I got some issues saying reading 0 bytes files or something however the file isnt empty... 
Also using fastparquet==0.7.1

Comment: Have you been able to read the file with any library (e.g. the java one) or via command line tools?  It sounds like maybe the file is malformed?

Comment: No I havent yet, I agree, I thaught about a permission issue but it doesnt look like it cause it's still about to enter the file information if it looks for the schema

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me while I was doing it with a compression schema of

```
df.to_parquet("sample.parquet",compression="uncompressed")
```

I changed it to none. Then it started working.

```
df.to_parquet("sample.parquet",compression="none")
```

Maybe for your case environment is not setup correctly.
Try installing other engines such as **fastparquet or pyarrow.**